# After restoring to OS X Base System I can’t reinstall macOS

Tags: terminal, imac

For my late 2012 iMac  I clicked restore on Disk Utility and it restored it to “OS X BASE SYSTEM”.

I tried to reinstall macOS but it said the **disk was locked**. When I boot up my iMac it only boots in to recovery mode not macOS.

(I don’t really care if I lost all my data on it.)

Comment: This is all somewhat confused. You cannot install to the base system; that's just the recovery system held in RAM. You need to install to your actual drive.